# Wpf value not passed to viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a usercontrol with a textbox. The textbox text property is bound like this:

```
<TextBox Background="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=_this}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding ElementName="_this"
                 Path="VisibleValue"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                 Mode="TwoWay"
                 ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

codebehind:

```
public String VisibleValue
    {
        get { return _visibleValue; }

        set
        {
            if (_visibleValue == value) { return; }

            _visibleValue = value;

            SetValue(value);

            RaisePropertyChanged("VisibleValue");
        }
    }
```

The 'SetValue' method tries to convert the string to int, double etc... and sets The dependency property 'Value'. (if the input string is null or empty the 'Value' property will be set to null).

```
 public const string ValuePropertyName = "Value";    

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        ValuePropertyName,
        typeof(Object),
        typeof(NumericInput),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnValueChangedCallback));

 public Object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (Object)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

now in another view I'm using this usercontrol and I'm binding the value property:

```
<sharedControls:NumericInput Type="{x:Type sys:UInt16}"
                             Value="{Binding VehicleLine, TwoWay, PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And the VehicleLine property in the viewmodel:

```
 public ushort VehicleLine
    {
        get { return this.vehicleLine; }

        set
        {
            if (this.vehicleLine == value) { return; }

            this.vehicleLine = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("VehicleLine");
            RaiseVariantInfoChanged();
        }
    }
```

My problem now is: if I type into the textbox a random number like 1, 2, 3 ,4 the value is passed to my vehicle number like it should. But if the textbox is empty the Value dependency property is set to null but this wont be passed to my vehicleline property. The setter of this property is never called.

Can anyone explain me why?

Note: even if I change the vehicleline property type to object, the setter wont be called.

thank you in advance!

Comment: I wasn't aware that {Binding VehicleLine, TwoWay, PropertyChanged} is valid. I thought that Path was the only binding markup extension property that can be set implicitly. Have you tried setting Mode and UpdateSource trigger explictly?

Comment: Adding a PropertyChanged callback to the UIPropertyMetadata was preventing my dependency property setter from getting called for some reason. When I refactored my code to not use one, it worked for me.